# How to transform [04/07/19] to [Sun, 7 Apr] in Java?

Tags: java, date

I need to check that `04/07/19` is exactly `Sun, 7 Apr`.
This assertion is used in one of my tests.

Comment: did you mean you want to check that on 7th Apr, 2019 it is Sunday or not?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question has been asked and answered with variations very many times before. Do yourself the favour of searching before posting a question. You will get an answer faster and you will get the best answers (not that the ones already posted here are bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse a String to [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and format it back again to a String:

```
// create a date from the String input
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("04/07/19", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy", Locale.ENGLISH));
// format the date back to a new string
String result = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE, d MMM", Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(result);
```

The result is: `Sun, 7 Apr`

If you want to use another Language you can just change the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) parameter. The default is your system language.

To understand or change date format patterns [this reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) might help. It describes all the different symbols and meanings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void go() {
    String date = "04/07/19";

    DateTimeFormatter fromFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy");
    DateTimeFormatter toFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM");

    System.out.println(toFormatter.format(fromFormatter.parse(date)));
}
```

Yields `Sun, 7 Apr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LocalDate class (available since java 8) with a DateTimeFormatter. This is an example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("04/07/19",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy"));
        System.out.println( date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM")));
        //If you need the day of the week
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println("Day of week : "+dayOfWeek);
    }
```

It'll print :

> Sun, 7 Apr
>
> Day of week : SUNDAY

Hope this can help you